# Show the map $g:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $g(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) = (\cos(a\theta), \sin(a\theta))$ is open where $a\in\Bbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, open-map

For a function $g: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $g(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) = (\cos(a\theta), \sin(a\theta))$ where $a$ is an integer, how do I show $g$ is an open map? I know that the idea is to show that for all open sets $U$ of $\mathbb{S}^1, g(U)$ is open. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: For $\theta_0<\theta_1$ let $I(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\{\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle:\theta_0<\theta<\theta_1\}$; the sets $I(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ are a base for the topology of $\Bbb S^1$, and it suffices to show that each $g[I(\theta_0,\theta_1)]$ is open in $\Bbb S^1$. What is $g[I(\theta_0,\theta_1)]$?

Answer (score 0):

The map $g$ is the restriction to $S^1$ of the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}G\colon&\Bbb C&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&z^a,\end{array}$$which is an open map, by the open mapping theorem. Therefore, $g$ is open too. You can also say that the restriction of $G$ to $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is open since $G'$ is never $0$.

Comment: How does the openness of $g$ follow from the openness of $G$?

Comment: If $A$ is an open subset of $S^1$, $A=A^\star\cap S^1$, for some open subset $A^\star$ of $\Bbb C$. But then $g(A)=G(A^\star)\cap S^1$. Since $G(A^\star)\cap S^1=g(A)$, $g(A)$ is open too.

Comment: I think the crucial equality $g(A) = G(A^*) \cap S^1$ is not obvious and needs further justification, e.g. using the fact that $S^1 = g^{-1}[S^1]$.

Comment: The map $G$ maps $S^1$ into $S^1$ and maps numbers outside $S^1$ into numbers outside $S^1$. That's enough.

Answer (score 0):

The map $f(z)=z^a$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ is open for non zero integers $a$ by open mapping theorem.Restrict it to $S^1$ now and use the fact that the standard topology on $S^1$ is the subspace topology endowed by the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How does the openness of the restriction follow from the openness of $f$?

Comment: Good question.I was expecting this.As a matter of fact,it's true that the restriction of an open map is not necessarily open,but there is an 'if' here.When we speak of open sets,we speak with respect to some ambient space.If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is open,it's not necessarily true that it's restriction to a subset $A$ must be open when the codomain remains $Y$.But in this case it's indeed true when the codomain is restricted to $S^1$ too,and also due to the fact that $S^1$ is invariant under $f$.I am showing why in the next comment.

Comment: See,for an open subset $U \cap S^1$ of $S^1$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ we of course have $f(U\cap S^1)\subset f(U)\cap f(S^1)$.It remand to show the reverse inclusion.Let $f(z) \in f(U) \cap f(S^1)$ for some $z\in U$.Since $f(S^1)\subset S^1$ here, $f(z) \in S^1$, which means $|z|^a = 1$.But since $|z|$ is positive,this is possible only when $|z|=1$,implying $z \in S^1$.Thus $z \in U \cap S^1$ and hence, $f(z) \in f(U \cap S^1)$.Thus $f(U\cap S^1)=f(U) \cap S^1$.Since $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, this restriction is open in $S^1$.Hope this helps.